# Prevent mouse-3 on mode-line from closing the window

Tags: window, mode-line

From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line-Mouse.html :

> mouse-3 on a mode line deletes the window it belongs to. If the frame has only one window, it does nothing.

I want to disable this behavior. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unbind it:

```
(global-set-key [mode-line mouse-3] nil)
```

To bind it to a different command:

```
(global-set-key [mode-line mouse-3] 'my-favorite-command)
```

How did I find this?

`C-h k`, then right-click the mouse on the mode-line, somewhere where there is no text.

That tells you:

> `<mode-line> <mouse-3>` (translated from `<down-mouse-3> <mouse-3>`) at
>   that spot runs the command `mouse-delete-window`, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `mouse.el`.
>
> It is bound to `<mode-line> <mouse-3>`.
>
> `(mouse-delete-window CLICK)`
>
> Delete the window you click on.
>
> Do nothing if the frame has just one window.
>
> This command must be bound to a mouse click.

If you then click the `mouse.el` link it takes you to the command definition. Searching for that command name in the same file, you come across this:

```
(global-set-key [mode-line mouse-3] 'mouse-delete-window)
```

You can copy that, changing the command name or replacing it by `nil`.

---

Update: I should have also mentioned what @Faried Nawaz mentions, which is a simpler way to unbind the key: use `global-unset-key`.  (So please consider upvoting that answer too.)  The result is the same as binding the command to `nil`.  Here is the definition (from `subr.el`):

```el
(defun global-unset-key (key)
  "Remove global binding of KEY.
KEY is a string or vector representing a sequence of keystrokes."
  (interactive "kUnset key globally: ")
  (global-set-key key nil))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Unluckily, my own former attempt of `M-x describe-key` failed because, as you say, one has to click _somewhere where there is no text_.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate this:

```
(global-unset-key [mode-line mouse-3])
```

You might want to `M-x customize-variable RET mode-line-default-help-echo RET` as well, but that's optional.